# Как прописать доступ к базе данных через connect.php?

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Помогите, пожалуйста!)

Когда заливаю на сайт, пишет

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to MySQL server on '123.123.123' (111 "Connection refused") in /home/123/public_html/connect.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/123/public_html/connect.php on line 7

Вот сам код в Connect.php:

```
?
$host = "123.123.123";

$user = "123";

$pass = "123";

$base = "123";

$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass); mysql_select_db($base, $con);

if (!$con) { echo "Нет соединения с базой данных."; exit; }

@mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");
?>
```

Что здесь исправить?
P.S. 123 - за место настоящих данных.

Comment: Полагаю, ответ на Ваш вопрос кроется в логах MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

У тебя MySQL сбрасывает соединение. Проверь доступы, пароли